# Finding period of a square wave with varying sampling frequency

Tags: matlab, signal-processing, discrete-mathematics

I have a square wave (0-1.8V) with a varying sampling frequency (from a circuit simulator). It is also not a perfect square wave (the high and low signal could be very close to but not precisely zero or 1 Volt) and the fall time is slightly slower than the rise time.

Another factor is that I will retake the data and the period (and possibly duty cycle as well) will change when I alter another parameter, so I am not working with a fixed number of cycles per window.

I tried autocorrelation but it seems that it gave me double or so the actual period. And fft seems to need a fixed sampling rate.  **What would be the best solution to finding the period of this square wave?**

[image]

Comment: Can you resample to fixed rate (using [`interp1`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/interp1.html) for example) and then apply correlation or DFT?

Comment: See whether this page about "Spectral Analysis of Nonuniformly Sampled Signals" helps you. https://www.mathworks.com/help/signal/examples/spectral-analysis-of-nonuniformly-sampled-signals.html

Comment: I cant really resample because I dont want to lose any information and the sample vector would be extremely long, too long for MATLAB

Comment: Have you got any information on the sampling proedure? Meaning how the sampling rate changes?

Comment: Well as far as I know, the circuit simulator takes more samples near the rising/falling edges and less on flat parts.  Maybe 10x or 100x more on these edges

Comment: Have you considered to ask the question here [dsp](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/) as this is more of a signal processing question and not programming?

Answer (score 0):

I would use diff, find the peaks (using findpeaks), both maxima and minima, and find the cycle time. Seems simple and computationally efficient.